# Pass EnumType to Postgres Function

Tags: java, postgresql, enums, enumerable

First.... I have a postgres function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth.MyFunction (
  platform autorizacion.e_tipo_plataforma, //Enum Type
  pAppId varchar,
  pVersion integer
)
```

when `e_tipo_plataforma` is:

```
CREATE TYPE autorizacion.e_tipo_plataforma AS ENUM (
'Web', 'Escritorio', 'Movil', 'Servicio');
```

As you can see a param for call the function is a `Enum Type` (e_tipo_plataforma)

I'm trying to send this EnumType to a Postgres `CallableStatement`:

```
String query="{call auth.MyFunction(?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement ps=conn.prepareCall(funcionLlamar);
```

1st Intent: `ps.setObject("p_tipo_plataforma", usuario.tipoPlataforma);`
where

`usuario.tipoPlataforma`
[image]

Error:

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.setObject(String,Object) is
>   not yet implemented.

2nd intent: `ps.setObject(1, usuario.tipoPlataforma.name());`

ERROR:

> function auth.MyFunction(character varying, character varying,
>   integer) does not exist

**UPDATE:**
3rd Intent: `ps.setObject(1, usuario.tipoPlataforma);`

ERROR:

> Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of
>   enumerator.TipoPlataforma. Use setObject()
>   with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

The question is, how can send as parameter a EnumType if the function in postgres only accept this type?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass enum values as strings (assuming the names of your Java and PostgreSQL enums match, of course!), and leave the heavy lifting of converting the string to an enum to the database:

```
ps.setString("p_tipo_plataforma", usuario.tipoPlataforma.name());
```

Comment: It pass...but when execute:

ps.setString(2,usuario.identificadorAplicacion);
ps.setInt(3,usuario.version);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

gives me the next error:
"ERROR: function auth.MyFunction (character varying, character varying, integer) does not exist"...........

because the function expect a EnumType as param not a character

Comment: Create another function that accepts the string variation of the enum.  Then have that function call your original function converting the string to an enum `auth.MyFunction (theEnumAsString::autorizacion.e_tipo_plataforma, pAppId, pVersion)`